# Windows 10 - Possible to shortcut AppData folder to external drive?

Tags: windows, permissions, external-hard-drive, shortcuts, symbolic-link

**Backstory**

- **C Drive** >> internal 256gb solid state drive - Windows installed here
- **D Drive** >> internal 1tb 7200rpm drive - strictly extra space

I tried to create a symbolic link from

```
C:/Users/Jackson/AppData
```

to

```
D:/Users/Jackson/AppData
```

all in effort to reduce the space used on my C drive but Windows continues to say I don't have permissions to do this.

**Question**

Is this possible? Maybe there is a more effecient way ie doing a shortcut for my entire user folder to D drive.

Comment: On a very fullsome machine that folder is less than 10 GB and is not meant to be relocated.

Comment: Why are you creating a symbolic link instead of just moving the folder altogether?  You likely are having a problem because you are attempting to create a symbolic link while you are logged into the profile.

Comment: @John Mine is at 12.6 so I am O K but on another machine the drive is a lot smaller. Since the folder is not meant to be moved what is my alternative aside from buying a bigger SSD ?

Comment: Best is to get a bigger drive rather than to change the way Windows requires itself to work.

Answer (score 0):

To make a symbolic link like that, you should first move the appdata folder to D:\users\jackson\appdata, delete the appdata folder on C and then run `mklink /J C:\users\jackson\appdata D:\users\jackson\appdata`.

If Windows is using the files in AppData folder, you should do this while you're not logged in.